# Tag synonym request: [snappy] -> [ubuntu-core]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I have no idea why but people like to call the Ubuntu Core system Snappy.

As a result, we have [snappy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snappy) and [ubuntu-core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-core) tags as separated when they are used for the same reason.

Here is an example: [How to Load Ubuntu Core "Snap" as custom image on MAAS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/564613/62483)

You can see on the previous thread it has both tags on the same question.

Lets make them a synonym!

Comment: Good idea, I just can't find the right button..

Comment: *A call to UI crowd..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone ahead and created the synonym, now that I found where SE hides that button.

Comment: A screen-shoot to help others would be great & funny :D

Comment: I'm afraid it really wasn't all that interesting @Lucio.. Just two text fields :/

Comment: Can we revisit this, snappy or snaps have come to mean the packages/ package system, and is now on more than just ubuntu-core, it now has a desktop version snappy-personal, and is planed to be on the phones/tablets as well.